# JavaScript Form / What is wrong here?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, popupwindow

I have two html pages, A and B. A openes B as popup. B should open its content back in A, but it does not. B has target='_parent', which should be the opening frame. What is wrong ? How can be this done ? You can test this by saving the snippets bellow in two files, a.html and b.html.

Submiting the form A should open into popup B, submiting B should load in A. B than should close.

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" onSubmit="window.open( 'b.html', '_blank',    'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');">
    <h1>Page A</h1>
    <label>
        <span>Your Name :</span>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" />
    </label>    
     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" /> 
    </label>    
</form>
```

And b.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" onSubmit="window.open('b.html','_parent','');" >
    <h1> Page B</h1>
    <label>
        <span>Your Email :</span>
        <input id="email" type="email" name="email"/>
    </label>
     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send" /> 
    </label>    
</form>
```

Comment: `_parent` is the parent *frame*, not the parent window.

Answer (score 2):

Your page `b.html` will require some Javascript code to copy the value of <input> element `email` back to the original page.  You will find that [Window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.opener) provides the reference you will need to manipulate the DOM in page A.

Answer (score -1):

I think u can use direct fill name `<form method="post" onSubmit="window.open( 'a.html');">` for b.html form tag ..

Thanks

Comment: Submiting the form B should open in the initial frame A. This is the requirement : A opens a popup B, the popup B submits back into A. Using window.open('a.html') will open in B again.